# Why Japanese IME always send WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE?

Tags: windows, message, ime

i don't know about Japanese IME's  when user change the IME ex) Microsoft IME -> Google IME

when i change the chinese ime in Chinese Language, like Pinyin -> Shuang Pin
They don't send the message to window anything.

but when i change japanese ime, they alwasys send the message WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE
but my language is still Japanese. 
there is no language changing. this is a changing of ime.

i want to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Answer my question because i find the problem.
if someone has a same problem, i want to give you some hint.

when Keyboard Layout Change, it should be occur WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE.
windows has a default Keyboard layout. and you can find these layout in registry.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts

Alomost IME is matched one by one as a language.
but Google IME is special.

Japanese GoogleIME has it's own Keyboard Layout.
so, when i try to switch from Microsoft IME to Google IME, 
this is not a switching of IME. 
this is a Changing of Keyboard Layout.

i didn't check all of IMEs but i think Some IME has their own Keyboard layout.

this is why WM_INPULANGCHAGE Message is Called.